# Many values being added to array onChange (INPUT)

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, vector

I'm developing an application based on React with a form included, first, the user has to type how many persons there are, then the user will have to type the age of each person. If user types 4 it will render 4 inputs.

[image]
[image]

I'm calling onChange function to setState for each age inside an array:

```
  <input onChange={e => {this.setState({
    idades: [... this.state.idades, e.target.value]
  })}}/>
```

The problem is, if I type age for any person for example: `21`, it will add to the array: `["2","21"]` instead of adding `["21"]`. If I erase the whole input and write `3` the array will be: `["2", "21", "2", "", "3"]`.

Comment: Dear Ibrahim, I really wanna help you but please explain a little more about your problem.

Comment: Hello @AmerllicA, thanks for the message. When I change the input's value it adds new values to array instead of updating it.

Comment: Dear @IbrahimOrra, you should distinguish the stats values for each new `input` I think the issue is related to your architect, think hard and design a dynamic state. I try to answer your question but you try for yourself more than me.

Comment: @AmerllicA Well, I think I will have review the way I'm calling the inputs. Thanks for the motivation. heheh :)

Comment: Thanks for your kindness, I leave an answer based on my understanding of your problem and leave an upvote to your post for more motivation ;)

Answer (score 1):

Set state to an object where key is the index of input, value is the value user inserts. Like so:

```
{
 0: 21,
 1: 3
}
```

Then update the state:

```
const context = this;
[...Array(this.state.numberOfPersons)].map((e, index) => 
  <input 
    key={index} 
    onChange={ev => {
      context.setState(prevState => ({
        idades: {
          ...prevState.idades,
          [index] = ev.target.value
        }
      }))}
    }
  />)
```

Comment: Hey Mike, thanks for the answer. Can you give me an example, please?

Comment: Hey Ibrahim, Updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should make a dynamic `state` for your component like below:

```
import React, { PureComponent } from 'react';

class YourCompo extends PureComponent {
  state = {
    inputArr: [],
  };

  handleNumberOfInputs = e =>
    this.setState({
      inputArr: Array(e.target.value)
        .fill()
        .map((_, index) => ({ key: index, value: '' })),
    });

  handleChangeOfNewInputs = index => e => {
    const { inputArr } = this.state;
    const newInputArr = inputArr.map(
      (item, i) =>
        index === i ? { key: item.key, value: e.target.value } : item
    );

    this.setState({
      inputArr: newInputArr,
    });
  };

  render() {
    const { inputArr } = this.state;

    return (
      <div>
        <input type="number" onChange={this.handleNumberOfInputs} />
        {inputArr.map(({ key, value }, index) => (
          <input
            key={key}
            value={value}
            type="number"
            onChange={this.handleChangeOfNewInputs(index)}
          />
        ))}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default YourCompo;
```

It could be written by Hooks but I think this answer could be more readable for you, maybe it doesn't satisfy your desire but it has its potential.